# Change periods to commas and vice versa in UDF

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have this Excel UDF to exclude all non-numeric characters from a cell, except periods and commas;
But before it cleans my number I would like to change all commas to periods and vice versa. I have no idea where to make this change in my code. Thanks

```
Function cleannumber(texto As String) As String 
Dim volta As String 
Dim pedaco As String 

volta = "" 
For i = 1 To Len(texto) 
   pedaco = Mid(texto, i, 1) 
   If pedaco >= "0" And pedaco <= "9"  Or pedaco = “,” Or pedaco =”.” Then volta = volta & pedaco 
Next i 
cleannumber = volta 
End Function
```

Comment: Are you looking for Replace() function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt3szac5%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?

Comment: Can i insert that function in my udf function to change commas to dots and viceversa before a clean my cell number?

Comment: like this: the periods and commas dissapear

Comment: For future reference, a function in VBA should *return* something, while a subroutine should *do* something. Here you have a function doing both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the `If` Statement :

```
pedaco = Replace(pedaco, ".", "whatever")
pedaco = Replace(pedaco, ",", ".")
pedaco = Replace(pedaco, "whatever", ",")
```

Comment: like this, the periods and commas are excluded

Function cleannumber(texto As String) As String 
Dim volta As String 
Dim pedaco As String 

volta = "" 

For i = 1 To Len(texto) 
pedaco = Mid(texto, i, 1) 
pedaco = Replace(pedaco, ".", ",")
pedaco = Replace(pedaco, ",", ".")

If pedaco >= "0" And pedaco <= "9"  Or pedaco = “,” Or pedaço =”.” Then volta = volta & pedaco 
Next i 
cleannumber = volta 
End Function
Before the If:

Comment: Now I understood!


pedaco = Replace(pedaco, ".", "whatever")
pedaco = Replace(pedaco, ",", ".")
pedaco = Replace(pedaco, "whatever", ",")

Fantastico!!!
Thanks a lot

Comment: I works fine for me... Thanks again. I would just like to understand why i.e
3,789.90 is converted in 3789,90 with no dot.. I can allways add the dot by changing the number format. But Id really like to understand why the dot dissapeared

Comment: @Emanuel I do not understand your comment.

Comment: your routine excludes de dot i.e 3,789.90 is converted to 3789,90

Comment: Your answer is the best I had so far, but the dot is removed from the number

Comment: @Emanuel  I think I understand the issue.......replace `cleannumber=volta` with `cleannumber="'" & volta` ...........this places a **single quote** at the beginning of the string and avoids Regional Settings problems.

Comment: Now its Perfect!!! you saved me a lot  of work Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Modified Code:

```
Function cleannumber(texto As String) As String 
Dim volta As String 
Dim pedaco As String 

volta = "" 
For i = 1 To Len(texto) 
   pedaco = Mid(texto, i, 1) 

   // Add the below line
   pedaco = Replace(pedaco, ",", ".")

   If pedaco >= "0" And pedaco <= "9"  Or pedaco = “,” Or pedaco =”.” Then volta = volta & pedaco 
Next i 
cleannumber="'" & volta
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, but like that, i.e 5,675.90 is converted in 5.675.90
I was expecting 5,675.90 to be converted to 5.675,90

Comment: you said you have to replace the ',' with dot so the above code does what you asked for.

Comment: if you want to replace the dot '.' to comma ',' then in the above code change the comma with the dot and dot with the comma.

Comment: Thanks everyone I really appreciate the attention. My problem is solved!

Comment: Oky, then edit our answer and approve the correct answer for others users if the encounter the same problem. :)